# Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Notifs)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to connect the redux-notifications to my project but it gives me that.

App.js

```
  class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.initializeApp();
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Navbar />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  initialized: state.app.initialized,
  authenticated: state.auth.token !== null
})

let AppContainer = compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, { initializeApp }))(App);

const MaterialsApp = (props) => {
  return (<div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Notifs />
      <Router history={history} >
        <AppContainer />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>
  );
}
```

store.js

```
 import { reducer as notifReducer } from 'redux-notifications';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  notifs: notifReducer,
});

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

Where is the problem? I tried to rewrite app.js and index.js, but it gives me that again